# CBOE Option Sentiment alternative datasource

Tags: options, market-data, data-source, sentiment

I am interested in CBOEs Option Sentiment data (https://datashop.cboe.com/option-sentiment)
It contains high level (aggregated) Options data on a daily basis delivered in a csv file. Main Datafields:Underlying, Call Volume, Put Volume, Count of Call Trades, Count of Put Trades, Total Underlying Volume, Total Dollar Call VOlume, Total Dollar Put Volume, Call OI, Put OI, Underlying Close.

However the Original CBOE data is very expensive, unaffordable for me as a private trader. Is anyone aware of an alternative datasource for this information? Maybe a reseller? I searched a lot, but couldn't find one. I would accept delayed data, if it lowers the price. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: From a conceptual point, it is part of the exchanges business to sell data. If some reseller could just sell the same data cheaper than the exchange, no one would be willing to pay the exchanges price.